# Bootstrap 4 - Dropdowns only work one times with tabs menu

Tags: toggle, dropdown, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

In bootstrap-4, the first time I click a dropdown in a tab menu it works fine, but after that it stops working.

```html
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#action" data-toggle="tab">action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#action_2" data-toggle="tab">Another action</a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    HOME
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    PROFILE
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="action">
    ACTION 1
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="action_2">
    ACTION 2
  </div>
</div>
```

#### [Here's a Demo in Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DrcnERfrer)

Comment: see here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17371

Comment: @BassJobsen Thank you so much :)

Comment: Are you using rails?  If so this might be related to turbolinks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by not clearing the `.active` class from the dropdown item when another tab is opened, therefore leaving it highlighted and preventing the same dropdown item from being clicked again.

According to the workaround in [Issue #17371 - navs dropdown tab bug](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17371), you can add the following js until the issue is resolved:

```js
$('.nav-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', 'a', function (e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget) {
        $(e.relatedTarget).removeClass('active');
    }
})
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
$('.nav-tabs').on('shown.bs.tab', 'a', function (e) {
    if (e.relatedTarget) {
        $(e.relatedTarget).removeClass('active');
    }
})
```

```html
<!-- 4.0.0-alpha.2 Libraries -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#action" data-toggle="tab">action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#action_2" data-toggle="tab">Another action</a>
    </div>
  </li>

</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
    HOME
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    PROFILE
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="action">
    ACTION 1
  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="action_2">
    ACTION 2
  </div>
</div>
```