# Bootstrap 4 Tabs - Only work on first click?

Tags: bootstrap-4, tabs

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--  Yellow Section   -->
<div class="accordion" id="expandInfo">
  <section id="yello" class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12" role="tabpanel">
          <!-- Nav tabs -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <!--start featured video -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 text-center panel">
              <h3 class="iconyell">Featured Video</h3>
              <p>Women's Self-Defense</p>
              <li role="presentation" class="active">
                <a href="#viewVideo" aria-controls="viewVideo" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                  <button type="button" class="btn">SEE VIDEO</button>
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
            <!--end featured video -->
            <!-- start train -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 text-center panel">
              <h3 class="iconyell">Train With Us</h3>
              <p>Why You Should</p>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#whyUs" aria-controls="whyUs" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                  <button type="button" class="btn">WHY US?</button>
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
            <!--end train-->
            <!--start instruct -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 text-center panel">
              <h3 class="iconyell">Your Instructor</h3>
              <p>Get To Know Us</p>
              <li role="presentation">
                <a href="#yourInstructor" aria-controls="yourInstructor" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                  <button type="button" class="btn">MEET US</button>
                </a>
              </li>
            </div>
            <!--end instruct-->
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content" id="tabs-collapse">
    <!--start viewVideo  area -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="viewVideo">
      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;background-color: white">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 su-youtube" style="width: 90%">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/WVm3D9kqows"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7" style="padding: 20px;">
          <h2 class="whyUsheader">Women's Self-Defense Course</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end viewVideo  area -->
    <!--start whyUs  area -->
    <!--start whyUs  area -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="whyUs">
      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;background-color: white">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="embed-responsive">
            <img src="image/why-join-mousels-mixed-martial-arts.JPG" width="442" height="370" alt="Why join Mousel's Mixed Martial Arts Academy" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded mx-auto d-block">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="whyUsheader">Why you should choose us...</h2>
          <p class="abouttitle">Sharing knowledge and helping others reach their full potential is what we do best.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end whyUs  area -->
    <!--end whyUs  area -->
    <!--start yourInstructor  area -->
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in" id="yourInstructor">
      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;background-color: white">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h2 class="whyUsheader text-center">Tim Mousel</h2>
          <p class="whyUstext py-4 px-0">Tim Mousel is the owner of&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.defend.net/">Mousel's Mixed Martial Arts Academy</a>,
            <a href="https://www.womens-self-defense.org/">Women's Self-Defense</a>, and
            <a href="https://www.edge-trainer.com/">The Edge Personal Training</a>.
          </p>
          <p class="whyUstext py-4 px-0">Tim has trained many of Houston's top martial arts instructors and has students he has trained compete at the highest levels of mixed martial arts competition including the
            <strong>Ultimate Fighting  Championship</strong> (UFC),
            <strong>King of the Cage</strong>,
            <strong>Pride</strong>, national kickboxing and Thai boxing championships, amateur and professional boxing.&nbsp; Tim was also the Strength and Conditioning Coach for two-time world boxing champion&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.reggiesweetjohnson.com/" target="_blank">Reggie Johnson</a>.

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--end yourInstructor  area -->
  </div>
</div>
<!--end container-->
```

When I click on a tab it shows the tab content, but if I click on it a second time, it doesn't.  You can see that in action at bootply:
https://www.bootply.com/4gEG55Wgr4

I've tried the advice suggested at [Bootstrap 4 - Dropdowns only work one times with tabs menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34025624/bootstrap-4-dropdowns-only-work-one-times-with-tabs-menu), but it didn't make any difference.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated,

Tim

Comment: `a` doesn't change from active class after the first click in your code. Tweak it around by making `a` as a parent. Below is the working snippet for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below snippet. Here `<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="tabNo" data-toggle="tab" href="#myTabN o" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">` should be the parent element as the `class ="active"` changes on change of tab

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--  Yellow Section   -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link " id="tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="#myTab1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h3 class="iconyell">Featured Video</h3>
          <p>Women's Self-Defense</p>
          <li role="presentation" class="active">

            <button type="button" class="btn">SEE VIDEO</button>

          </li>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="tab2" data-toggle="tab" href="#myTab2" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">
        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
          <h3 class="iconyell">Train With Us</h3>
          <p>Why You Should</p>
          <li role="presentation">

            <button type="button" class="btn">WHY US?</button>

          </li>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="tab3" data-toggle="tab" href="#myTab3" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">
        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
          <h3 class="iconyell">Your Instructor</h3>
          <p>Get To Know Us</p>
          <li role="presentation">
            <button type="button" class="btn">MEET US</button>

          </li>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content " id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade " id="myTab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1">

      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;background-color: white">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3 su-youtube" style="width: 90%">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/WVm3D9kqows"></iframe>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7" style="padding: 20px;">
          <h2 class="whyUsheader">Women's Self-Defense Course</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="myTab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2">
      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;background-color: white">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="embed-responsive">
            <img src="image/why-join-mousels-mixed-martial-arts.JPG" width="442" height="370" alt="Why join Mousel's Mixed Martial Arts Academy" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail rounded mx-auto d-block">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
          <h2 class="whyUsheader">Why you should choose us...</h2>
          <p class="abouttitle">Sharing knowledge and helping others reach their full potential is what we do best.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="myTab3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab3">
      <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;background-color: white">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <h2 class="whyUsheader text-center">Tim Mousel</h2>
          <p class="whyUstext py-4 px-0">Tim Mousel is the owner of&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.defend.net/">Mousel's Mixed Martial Arts Academy</a>,
            <a href="https://www.womens-self-defense.org/">Women's Self-Defense</a>, and
            <a href="https://www.edge-trainer.com/">The Edge Personal Training</a>.
          </p>
          <p class="whyUstext py-4 px-0">Tim has trained many of Houston's top martial arts instructors and has students he has trained compete at the highest levels of mixed martial arts competition including the
            <strong>Ultimate Fighting Championship</strong> (UFC),
            <strong>King of the Cage</strong>,
            <strong>Pride</strong>, national kickboxing and Thai boxing championships, amateur and professional boxing.&nbsp; Tim was also the Strength and Conditioning Coach for two-time world boxing champion&nbsp;
            <a href="http://www.reggiesweetjohnson.com/" target="_blank">Reggie Johnson</a>.

          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!--end container-->
```

Comment: Thank you again! I'm trying to make this scroll to the open tab content modifying the code you supplied for my last question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570191/bootstrap-4-accordian-scroll-to-open-content/56575046?noredirect=1#comment99729440_56575046)  I've also tried this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088649/bootstrap-tabs-scroll-effect-to-content-when-clicked

Would it be possible for you to tweak that to work with your new code or should I ask that as a new question?  

Thank for all your help!